# Can I use a background task to process data from a server every 1 sec?

Tags: android, ios, mysql, background-process

I'd like to dedicate 1% of the processing power of each device my app is installed into for the greater good. A background task should start running once you open the app and continue when you exit the app for multitasking purposes.

**Background Task**

1. Download small amounts of data (<1KB) every 1 sec.
2. Process them using 1% of the processing power of the device.
3. Rarely, upload small amounts of data (<1KB).

In the example below I'm using MySQL but it will certainly not be done with MySQL.

Also, note that the actual numbers will be largely ***optimized in the end*** and that's where the 1% figure comes from.

Obviously, I can't specifically tell the device to use 1% of its processing power.

**Open App**

Connect to a MySQL server.

**Download Data**

It should read a cell in the MySQL database with data less than 1KB in size every 1 sec.

**Processing**

Requires reading a relatively large amount of data (1MB) from the device every 1 sec.

**Upload Data**

Rarely, it should write a cell in the MySQL database with data less than 1KB in size.

**Kill App**

Disconnect from the database.

I figured, where mobile devices excel is their *memory speed* and *internet connectivity*.

Will repeatedly reading from a MySQL database and the disk of the device hog it's performance and battery life?

**Most importantly, does iOS and Android allow for complex background tasks of this kind?**

Comment: what do you mean 'for the greater good'?

Comment: I'll have to explain the entire project and I don't like to get into the details. This will make it very long.

Comment: For Android you can use a foreground service if it needs to run continually. That way the service will not be killed by the OS and the users will be aware of the process (which of course they should). You can also check WorkManager but it doesn't seem to be what you need here except maybe for the uploading part.

Comment: What about iOS? Can I use multiple types of background processes? I will try to find workarounds for the limitations.

Comment: To answer one of your questions: Yes, doing network access every second will kill the phone's battery fairly quickly.  Radios use a lot of power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android allows for these complex background tasks but iOS does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `services` for this purpose:

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Answer (score 0):

No, iOS does not support this kind of background processing (executing continually)

You can request that iOS schedule background work using a [BGProcessingTaskRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtaskrequest).  Using this API you specify that the task should only execute when the device is connected to external power and the network is available.

These tasks are limited to a few minutes duration for each invocation and although you can request an "earliest start date" you cannot specify a specific start time nor an execution frequency.

Comment: I wouldn't want to run a background process without the app being visible in multitasking. If you download MyApp and open it, then switch to Facebook would I be able to perform tasks on MyApp while the user is browsing Facebook? This is different from having a background task/service without UI showing up in a task manager that the iOS lacks.

Comment: To answer my own question: I won't be able to perform tasks because the app gets suspended, only fetch some data in a variable cycle.